# Interfacing <Div>

Tags: css, html

This is my code:

```
<div id="divCategoryMenu" name="divCategoryMenu" style="background-color:#BCD2E6;">
  <ul id="ulCategoryMenu" name="ulCategoryMenu">

  </ul>
</div>
```

The list is dynamically filled. But there is a problem:

When the list fills inside this Div, the items are center-aligned by default when I have not used any align property in the above code and also in the code that I am using to dynamically fill it. How to align so that items appear and look like this:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b0f0daf6a2.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b0f0daf6a2.jpg)

At present it is displayed in a dirty form like this:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/901540953d.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/901540953d.jpg)

**** Edited ****

In my case, the items are actually labels not

. Secondly, what CSS to include to give it a look like the first image.

**** Edited further ****

The CSS code for the hard-coded HTML of the first image looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css">

.urbangreymenu{
width: 200px; /*width of menu*/
}

.urbangreymenu .headerbar{
font: bold 12px Verdana;
color: white;
background:#006699 url(media/arrowstop.gif) no-repeat 8px 6px; /*last 2 values are the x and y coordinates of bullet image*/
margin-bottom: 0; /*bottom spacing between header and rest of content*/
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 7px 0 7px 31px; /*31px is left indentation of header text*/
}

.urbangreymenu ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 0; /*bottom spacing between each UL and rest of content*/
}

.urbangreymenu ul li{
padding-bottom: 2px; /*bottom spacing between menu items*/
}

.urbangreymenu ul li a{
font: normal 12px Arial;
color: black;
background: #E4F0F5;
display: block;
padding: 5px 0;
line-height: 12px;
padding-left: 8px; /*link text is indented 8px*/
text-decoration: none;
}

.urbangreymenu ul li a:visited{
color: black;
}

.urbangreymenu ul li a:hover{ /*hover state CSS*/
color: white;
background: black;
}


.style14 {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
.style15 {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #006699; font-size: 11px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant existing CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like RegDwight says, it's about margin/padding not alignment. You have to add [the following style items](http://webforumz.com/html-xhtml-and-css/8197-align-list-to-the-left.htm) to your UL item, and also to the actual LI items of your list.
**Update:** Actually a little more had to be done to get the white spaces between the list items. See the code below.

Since the LI items are generated and not present on your initial HTML code, you have to define their styles in CSS as children of your UL item.

**Update**: I had to edit the code a little to make it look exactly like in your example. I've pasted the complete new HTML and CSS, it should be ok now.

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
.urbanbluemenu{
    width: 200px; /*width of menu*/
}

ul#ulCategoryMenu {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul#ulCategoryMenu li {
    background-color: #BCD2E6;
    margin: 2px 0 2px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="urbanbluemenu" id="divCategoryMenu" name="divCategoryMenu">
  <ul id="ulCategoryMenu" name="ulCategoryMenu">
     <li><label>John</label></li>
     <li><label>Bill</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot I would say that the items are *not* center-aligned, but rather offset from the left.

Try decreasing the `margin-left`/`padding-left` for your `#ulCategoryMenu`. As a quick example, try:

```
<ul id="ulCategoryMenu" name="ulCategoryMenu" style="margin-left:0;padding-left:0">
```

You might also have to decrease the left padding for your `li`s, depending on what CSS rules have been previously applied to them.

See also [Listamatic](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/vertical08.htm) for further inspiration.

Comment: I just removed the ul and li. Now I am showing the labels in a div. It appears well aligned but the colors and spacing between each item?

Comment: Frankly, I think you should keep your markup semantic. If you have an actual list, you shouldn't use div instead of ul. Besides, it's much easier to add the spacing between items if they *are* actual items (i.e., li tags).

Comment: Hey, dont remove the ul and li, you wanna have a list dont you? :) try my example below, with the original HTML

Answer (score 1):

Set margin to 0, a little padding-left and a line-height (maybe 20px) to your li elements.
By default, li have a margin-left/padding-left (depending on the navigator).

(The line-height if for the li to be more separated from each other. A padding-top and bottom can also works.)

Comment: Actually, he has to set the bottom and top margins to about 2px, a little padding-left, optionally a lineheight, and the right background colour on the LI items. I've worked out the code below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out and see if it works for you:

```
<div id="divCategoryMenu" name="divCategoryMenu" style="background-color:#BCD2E6;">
  <ul id="ulCategoryMenu" name="ulCategoryMenu" style="list-style:none;padding-left:-2px;margin-left-2px;">
    <li>Zilla Parishad</li>
    <li>Nagar Parishad</li>
    <li>Taluka Panchayat</li>
    <li>Gram Panchayat</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If your `<li>` elements are instead `<label>` elements, make sure they're properly wrapped in `<li>` tags.

Edit: of course, once you get the style worked out properly, you should move the styles to your stylesheet.

The above code should give you a list, with no bullets, and pull the list slightly to the left.

Comment: Labels are enclosed properly.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to assign the padding *and* margin for lists and list-items. The reason for this is twofold: 1, there are default settings for margin and padding that are typically undesired for navigable lists. 2, Firefox and IE handle their spacing differently, i.e., Firefox with use padding, IE margin (or vice versa, can't remember), and thus they both must be overridden in order for the final product to look the same in both browsers.

Additionally, the contents of an `ol` or `ul` must be `li`. If you have other elements, they must be wrapped in an `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the actual HTML generated?

Then the CSS applied to it?

Comment: HTML is a simple HTML but I am not following why it is right aligning.